# Synconization between Android and Server doubts

Tags: android, push

Recently in yo work, suggest the idea to develop a Android app that make (between other things) upload and sync data to a server.

This is possible but, we don't know how to do it for the momment..

We doubt is, ***how to synchronize data between the application and the server, and when the application loses signal or coverage (if not connected to a WiFi) and when it recovers the signal, which continue up the data to the server***.

We don't know what technology use or if this is possible.

What do you think about it? ***Exists any technology to do this? What Android API cal help us?***

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here are the some links which will help you to go ahead.

- http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html
- [Android Check Internet Connection using Broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179487/android-check-internet-connection-using-broadcast)
- [Broadcast receiver for checking internet connection in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a simple topic.

I stumbled across a [post](http://birbit.com/a-recipe-for-writing-responsive-rest-clients-on-android/?utm_source=Android%20Weekly&utm_campaign=30e70de17f-Android_Weekly_83&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_4eb677ad19-30e70de17f-337827373) recently that describes a reasonably robust strategy for handling keeping apps responsive while talking to servers and how to queue up transactions.
Watch the Google I/O video linked at the top of the post and read through the post.

You'll also want to read up about [watching change in network state](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html) so you know when to start synchronisation again.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion, it's interesting take the opinion of other developers.